# Get value from array in array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json

Here's the relevant part of my PHP:

```
$response2 = curl_exec( $ch2 );
$stuff2 = json_decode($response2, true);
$user_id = $stuff2['identities[0].user_id'];
```

The `$response` looks good, as does `$stuff2`. What I'm trying to get is the value for `user_id` and store as a variable I can use in PHP (`$user_id`). If I `var_dump` `$stuff2`, I get something like this:

```
array(2) {
 ["nickname"]=>
  string(3) "jmr"
  ["identities"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    array(2) {
      ["user_id"]=>
      string(24) "5458fec4aa0395931002fe71"
      ["connection"]=>
      string(32) "Username-Password-Authentication"

    }
  }
  }
```

If I do this:

```
$response2 = curl_exec( $ch2 );
$stuff2 = json_decode($response2, true);
$user_id = $stuff2['nickname'];
```

then I get "jmr" no problem, but I can't figure out how to get that "user_id" buried in that second array within the array.

Answer (score 3):

Do a `print_r($stuff2);` and you will see the array is just an ordinary multi-dimensional array. I'm not sure why you have that convoluted key, but you access it just like an ordinary multi-dimensional array:

```
$user_id = $stuff2['identities'][0]['user_id'];
```

Comment: `'identities[0].user_id'` <-- convoluted key

Comment: That's just how I was used to getting a value like this in jquery ajax, but apparently nothing like how you do it in php